# Content is missing but lof or toc keeps showing on top of first page

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

```
\documentclass[a4j]{jarticle}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section
...
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{fig/fig/sithf.eps}
        \caption{HF(sitstand)}
        \label{fig:hf}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

When I delete the `\tableofcontents`, the document content shows up, but the Table of Contents and the List of Figures are still there.

The toc (top) and the missing part (below) look like this:

[image: the toc (or the lof?!)]

[image: the missing part]

Comment: So you still have a `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` present, but not `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: if I add tableofcontents, some part of it will show up on the top but not in the content table. if I don't add, it still showed up(the graph above)

Comment: That can't be explained with the information you've provided. Ideally we'd like to replicate the results, as this would make it possible to provide you with answers as to the cause, and possibly how to fix it. Could you supply the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: after I delete some undefined symbol(which is a "space" but don't take a space), I think it's the japanese encoding problem.